# Nested loop over std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

In my simulation I have a particle class and a nbody class.

```
struct Particle{
    double m;           // mass
    double x[DIM];      // position
    double v[DIM];      // velocity
    double F[DIM];      // force 
    double F_old[DIM];  // force past time step
    void update_position(double dt);
    void update_velocity(double dt);
    void update_force(Particle*, Particle*);
};

class Nbody {
    private:
        const double dt;                // step size
        const double t_max;             // max simulation time
        std::vector<Particle> p;
    public:
        Nbody(unsigned int n_, double dt_, double t_max_);
        void comp_force();
        void comp_position();
        void comp_velocity();
};
```

I update the position of every particle by looping over every particle and calling `void Particle::update_position()`.

```
void Nbody::comp_position() {
    for (Particle& particle: p) { 
        particle.update_position(dt);
    }
}
```

In the following code snippet, I show the update rule to compute the new position.

```
void Particle::update_position(double dt) {
    const double a = dt * 0.5 / m;
    for (unsigned int d=0; d<DIM; ++d) {
        x[d] += dt * (v[d] + a * F[d]);
        F_old[d] = F[d];
    }
}
```

However, I have problems with the force calculation where I want to compute the interaction of particles and therefore need a nested loop. How can I do that? Here is my approach so far, which gives me an error:

```
void Particle::update_force(Particle* i, Particle* j) {
    double r=EPS; // smoothing
    for (unsigned int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        r += sqr(j->x[d] - i->x[d]);
    }
    const double f = i->m * j->m / (sqrt(r) * r);
    for (unsigned int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        i->F[d] += f * (j->x[d] - i->x[d]);
        j->F[d] -= f * (j->x[d] - i->x[d]);
    }
}

void Nbody::comp_force() {
    for (Particle& particle: p) {
        for (unsigned int d=0; d<DIM; ++d) {
            particle.F[d] = 0.;
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
            update_force(&p[i], &p[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
nbody.cpp: In member function ‘void Nbody::comp_force()’:
nbody.cpp:84:13: error: ‘update_force’ was not declared in this scope
             update_force(&p[i], &p[j]);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can I write this similar as the `update_position` method?

Comment: @uneven_mark Sorry, you are right. Will update my question.

Comment: Suggestion: Your position, velocity and force could all benefit from a vector class (not `std::vector` but a math vector). `template <size_t Dim> class Vector {...`

Comment: `Particle::update_force` is being called from `Nbody::comp_force`. Note the differing scopes.

Comment: Looks like `Particle::update_force` could be made `static` (or a `friend` free function, but `static` seems more appealing to me here).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Could you elaborate on your suggestion a little? I can't imagine how I could implement that.

Comment: @Samuel they share many things. A position is a vector in N dimensions from origo. Velocity is a vector of speed. Force is a vector with direction - which is why you've used an array of DIM axis for all of them. Create a class for it and you'll find that applying a force to a position or velocity to something with a position becomes easy. All the calculations are the same, with different units of course.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `update_force` defined as a member function on a `Particle` from a member function of `NBody`. There is no function `update_force` in the scope of `NBody`, hence the error. My suggestion would be to not define `update_force` as a member function on a particle, but as a free function outside `Particle`:

```
struct Particle{
    double m;           // mass
    double x[DIM];      // position
    double v[DIM];      // velocity
    double F[DIM];      // force 
    double F_old[DIM];  // force past time step
    void update_position(double dt);
    void update_velocity(double dt);
};

...

void update_particle_force(Particle& i, Particle& j) {
    double r=EPS; // smoothing
    for (unsigned int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        r += sqr(j.x[d] - i.x[d]);
    }
    const double f = i.m * j.m / (sqrt(r) * r);
    for (unsigned int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        i.F[d] += f * (j.x[d] - i.x[d]);
        j.F[d] -= f * (j.x[d] - i.x[d]);
    }
}
```

which is then called as:

```
...
update_particle_force(p[i], p[j]);
...
```

The advantage of using references over pointers for the parameters of `update_particle_force` is that to a certain extent you will avoid null pointer dereferences; the potential burden of the null pointer check is now on the caller of `update_particle_force`.

Comment: Huh. It didn't click that `Particle` was a `struct` That eliminates my objections to `update_force` being a free function.